# Checking if a field is empty fails, on a node template file

Tags: 7, entities

Trying to use `empty()` on a "longtext" field in a custom node template, the field is always reported not to be empty (whatever the field is empty or not).

```
<?php if (!empty($content['field_myfield'])): ?>
  <p>additional content</p>
  <?php print render($content['field_landing_petition']);?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Why doesn't it work?  How else could I test for empty fields in the template file for a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$content['field_myfield']` is an array containing some keys; if you pass that array to `empty()`, you would not get back `TRUE` as result.
For example, I added a three fields to a content type (their types are "taxonomy term reference," "decimal," and "list of float values"); what you see in `content['field_name']` is the following:

[image: decimal field]

[image: taxonomy term reference field]

[image: float list field]

`$content['field_name']['#items']` contains the content of the field; it's an array, as in Drupal 7 fields can contain multiple values.

The generic code that allows to check if the field is empty, which works for any field, without to know details about how the field values are stored, is similar to the following one:

```
// $field_name contains the name of the field.

$field = file_info_field($field_name);
$function = $field['module'] . '_field_is_empty';

foreach ((array) $content[$field_name]['#items'] as $item) {
  if (!$function($item, $field)) {
    $result = TRUE;
  } 
}

$is_empty = empty($result);
```

`$is_empty` is equal to `TRUE` when all the items of the field are empty, giving to *empty* the meaning given to the word from the module implementing the field. For example, the module could consider the field empty when its value is "none" or any similar value (e.g. "empty" or "`<none>`").

Comment: $field = file_info_field($field_name); - that line gives me a WSOD. Not using code on node template but on display suite code field.

Answer (score 0):

To improve kiamlaluno's answer - the really robust code to check if field is empty (in custom form validation) need to take care of languages as well:

```
$field = field_info_field('field_file'); // for example
$available_languages = field_available_languages($entity_type, $field);
$languages = _field_language_suggestion($available_languages, $options['language'], $key);
$valid = true;
foreach ($languages as $langcode) {
    if ($is_valid = my_validate_function($key, $field[$langcode])) {
        $valid = $valid && $is_valid;
    }
}
if ($valid) {
    // all lang fields are valid
}
```